# Взять в кавычки - PHP и JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Привет, вывожу в php вот такое

```
print" 
<script>
console.log('Населенный пункт: %s', firstGeoObject.getLocalities().join(', '));
 var citt = firstGeoObject.getLocalities().join(', '); 
alert(citt);
ymaps.route([ citt, { point: 'г. Москва Якуба Колоса', type: 'viaPoint' } 
</script>
"
```

как значение var citt = взять в одинарные кавыки ' '  ?

на данный момент выводит без ковычек - Москва, а надо 'Москва'

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.domManip (jquery.min.js:3)
    at n.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:3)
    at n.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at n.access (jquery.min.js:3)
    at n.fn.init.html (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.success (stranicza-kurera:323)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 2):

Если и выводить код js и html с помощью php, то так:

```
<?php
#php code
if( some_condition ) {
?>
<p> some text </p>
<script> </script>
<? } ?>
```

Конкретно по вашему вопросу: использовать символ экранирования: обратный слеш:

```
print" 
<script>
console.log('Населенный пункт: %s', firstGeoObject.getLocalities().join(', '));
 var citt = '\'' + firstGeoObject.getLocalities().join(', ') + '\''; 
alert(citt);
ymaps.route([ citt, { point: 'г. Москва Якуба Колоса', type: 'viaPoint' } 
</script>
"
```

Comment: а почему citt после route не выводит? alert выводит все ок 'Москва' и citt после route тоже так должен выводить

Comment: наверно эту строчку нужно чуть ниже переместить...